# Для чего теги "оборачивают" Wrapper'ом?

Tags: html, css

Для чего теги "оборачивают" Wrapper'ом и почему у Wrappera часто ставят `position:relative`? Что вообще дает использование wrapper'а?

Comment: В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

Comment: @Grundy, видимо, идентификатор `#wrapper` имеется в виду, и участник не знает, что можно задавать любые значения атрибутом `id` и `class`, а `wrapper` приводится только для примера. Berty, для чего `wrapper`, например, как [в этом примере](http://cssdeck.com/labs/2i9mbvpf) Вы хотели узнать? Спасибо.

Comment: @Саша Черных,я тут первый раз,так что,извиняюсь за неточную формулировку)Да,я бы хотел узнать.

Comment: Когда понадобится, сам поймёшь...

Answer (score 3):

Это может быть связано с `position:absolute` для вложенного элемента. Дело в том, что без обёртки с `position:relative` координаты такого элемента будут отсчитываться относительно всего документа, а с обёрткой - относительно обёрточного элемента.

Answer (score 3):

Это всего лишь контейнер для удобства, заключая блоки в обертку проще центрировать, задавать общую ширину..... и т.д.
Релейтив ставят если собираются абсолютно позиционировать внутренние блоки.

Answer (score 0):

В целом, `wrapper` используют для удобства позиционирования. Самому `wrapper`, присваивают минимум свойств.

Например:

`.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px; 
  padding-right: 10px; 
  padding-left: 10px;
}`

А иногда вообще оставляют его без них. Почему просто не оставлять див без класса? Во первых, противоречит некоторым методологиям (например БЭМ). Во вторых, слово "wrapper" переводится как "обертка" и дает понять, тем кто будет работать с кодом после вас, зачем этот `div` нужен (при беглом просмотре). Также, он может послужить прослойкой для функционирования различных скриптов.

[Исчерпывающая статья](http://css-live.ru/articles/luchshij-sposob-realizovat-obyortki-v-css.html)

Answer (score 0):

Банальный пример...
Допустим нам надо чтобы блок вытягивался снизу верх, но при этом должен быть где-то в середине... И тут без обертки не обойтись... Потому, что ему надо задать абсолютное позиционирование и bottom: 0;... Но без обертки его абсолютное позиционирование будет относительно body и будет выглядеть так...

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: all .5s;
}

div:hover {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

А с оберткой то, что надо...

```css
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

#wrap>div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#wrap>div:hover {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div></div>
</div>
```